# Asterisk - Position Announcement to First Caller

Tags: asterisk, queue

When Asterisk announces the position of a caller in the queue, it plays queue-thereare, followed by the caller's position, followed by queue-callswaiting. We have custom messages for each of these that work perfectly around the caller's position being announced.

However, it doesn't do this for the first call. Instead, it plays queue-youarenext followed by queue-thankyou. I can define it to play the other messages, but I'm not going to get the position announced. So our custom announcements work well for all but the first caller in line.

Is there a setting that will instruct the queue to not treat the first caller any different in this regard, such that it will play the same recordings along with the position announcement?

I know that there are alternate ways of doing this, like creating additional custom recordings. For now, I'm looking to see if this can be done solely through configuration without further modifying the recordings.

Comment: Maybe, but will this actually be useful to the caller?

Comment: @MichaelHampton That would be the only reason we'd do it.

Comment: In this case the position is always 1, so what's the point of saying anything other than you are next? This is why I question whether it will be useful for the caller.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think you may have misunderstood the question. It currently says "you are next" for the first caller and "you are caller N" for all others. I want it to treat the first caller like all others so it says "you are caller 1" instead of "you are next".

Comment: That's exactly what I thought you meant, and why I question why you are trying to do it at all. This will feel stilted and may confuse callers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton We have recorded messages that are meant to replace the "you are caller..." and "...waiting.. etc" that provide the same details but with more information. I don't agree that "you are caller 1..." isn't as clear to the caller as "you are next".